# fspromises.writeFile() Writes Empty File on process.exit()

Tags: node.js, promise, fs

I've been looking all over, but I can't seem to find the answer why I'm getting nothing in the file when exiting.

For context, I'm writing a discord bot. The bot stores its data once an hour. Sometime between stores I want to store the data in case I decide I want to update the bot. When I manually store the data with a command, then kill the process, things work fine. Now, I want to be able to just kill the process without having to manually send the command. So, I have a handler for SIGINT that stores the data the same way I was doing manually and after the promise is fulfilled, I exit. For some reason, the file contains nothing after the process ends. Here's the code (trimmed).

app.ts

```
function exit() {
  client.users.fetch(OWNER)
    .then(owner => owner.send('Rewards stored. Bot shutting down'))
    .then(() => process.exit());
}
process.once('SIGINT', () => {
  currencyService.storeRewards().then(exit);
});
process.once('exit', () => {
  currencyService.storeRewards().then(exit);
});
```

currency.service.ts

```
private guildCurrencies: Map<string, Map<string, number>> = new Map<string, Map<string, number>>();
storeRewards(): Promise<void[]> {
    const promises = new Array<Promise<void>>();
    this.guildCurrencies.forEach((memberCurrencies, guildId) => {
        promises.push(this.storageService.store(guildId, memberCurrencies));
    })
    return Promise.all(promises)
}
```

storage.service.ts

```
store(guild: string, currencies: Map<string, number>): Promise<void> {
    return writeFile(`${this.storageLocation}/${guild}.json`, JSON.stringify([...currencies]))
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('could not store currencies', err);
        })
}
```

So, as you can see, when SIGINT is received, I get the currency service to store its data, which maps guilds to guild member currencies which is a map of guild members to their rewards. It stores the data in different files (each guild gets its own file) using the storage service. The storage service returns a promise from writeFile (should be a promise of undefined when the file is finished writing). The currency service accumulates all the promises and returns a promise that resolves when all of the store promises resolve. Then, after all of the promises are resolved, a message is sent to the bot owner (me), which returns a promise. After that promise resolves, then we exit the process. It should be a clean exit with all the data written and the bot letting me know that it's shutting down, but when I read the file later, it's empty.

I've tried logging in all sorts of different places to make sure the steps are being done in the right order and I'm not getting weird async stuff, and everything seems to be proceeding as expected, but I'm still getting an empty file. I'm not sure what's going on, and I'd really appreciate some guidance.

EDIT: I remembered something else. As another debugging step, I tried reading the files after the currency service storeRewards() promise resolved, and the contents of the files were valid* (they contained valid data, but it was probably old data as the data doesn't change often). So, one of my thoughts is that the promise for writeFile resolves before the file is fully written, but that isn't indicated in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options).

EDIT 2: The answer was that I was writing twice. None of the code shown in the post or the first edit would have made it clear that I was having a double write issue, so I am adding the code causing the issue so that future readers can get the same conclusion.

Comment: I do not believe you can reliably run asynchronous code on an exit event.  At that point the process is already in the middle of the exiting procedure and won't wait for asynchronous operations to finish.  If possible, use synchronous I/O.  Since that is blocking, it will complete before exit.  Or, restructure the code so you can run your asynchronous I/O BEFORE the process is actually exiting.

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify, when you're saying exit event, are you talking about the SIGINT and similar events, or are you talking about process.exit(), because I'm not calling process.exit() until after the asynchronous writeFile promise has been resolved. As an added point, I still get the expected response on my other asynchronous events like sending a message and I even get logs that are supposed to come after the writeFile promise is resolved and those all seemed fine.

Comment: I was talking about when `process.exit()` has already been called.  I can't follow the logic flow of the snippets of code you show and I don't know all the things you are calling.  Perhaps something is not properly promisified so it resolves its promise before it's actually done.  For example, what is `writeFile()`?

Comment: Did you try adding a random sequence to the file paths to see if you're writing them twice? Also, when you say added debug printers, did those include the contents of `currencies` pre-write?

Comment: I added a random UUID and it is, indeed, writing twice. The issue, I found, is that I also had a process.once('exit', ...) that had the same code, so while it was exiting, it was writing a second time, but because exit was called, it dies before the file is rewritten. I've removed it, and hopefully I can find another way to prevent data loss when Windows decides to auto update. I'm going to update the question to add the crucial piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @leitning for their help finding the answer in the comments on my question. After writing a random UUID in the file name, I found the file was being written twice. I had assumed when asking the question, that I had shared all the relevant info, but I had missed something. process.once('exit', ...) was being called after calling process.exit() ([more details here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit)). The callback function for the exit event does not handle asynchronous calls. When the callback function returns, the process exits. Since I had duplicated the logic in the SIGINT callback function in the exit callback function, the file was being written a second time and the process was exiting before the file could be written, resulting in an empty file. Removing the process.once('exit', ...) logic fixed the issue.